# whereis python giving me 6 python locations

Tags: python, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am using `Window Subsystem Linux 2` with `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`. I am using it for a while and decided to check the `python` version installed in my machine.

I ran following command :

```
python3 -V
```

it displays

```
Python 3.8.10
```

after that I decided to upgrade my python version but before that I ran

`whereis python` and this command displaying me **6 locations** of python

Locations

1. `/usr/bin/python3.8`
2. `/usr/lib/python3.8`
3. `/usr/lib/python3.9`
4. `/usr/lib/python2.7`
5. `/etc/python3.8`
6. `/usr/local/lib/python3.8`

My question is, is it normal to have this much **python's** installed in your machine. And Secondly I want to make `python3.9` as my default `python3` currently I have `3.8` version.

Comment: 1. yes it's normal. 2. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu).

Comment: Most of these are not executables at all. In fact, only the first one is a working `python` binary. The standard Bash command to look for executables is `type` or `command -v`, not `whereis`.

Comment: You can create a virtual environment where python 3.9 is the default. But use care. On linux there are many system utiltiies that use python and they assume its whatever pythnon is standard for that release. Python is good at backwards compatability but you may find that some system utils fail. The windows subsysem may have the same issues.

Comment: @tdelaney Thank You! I think I is best to use `3.9` in virtual environment as you said!! rather installing or setting it globally.

Comment: Its not just a question of versions, its installed packages also. Things installed via your package manager (e.g., deb or rpm installers) are tested with each other. if you `pip` install things you risk messing up existing dependencies from your package manager. Its best to use a private python and virtual environments when you want to pull in the latest packages. I don't do that personally... but I do reinstall my notebook with some regularity.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal to have these many locations. **whereis** command allows to - locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command. although the lastest version of python is 3.x but few tools still work on python 2.x.

In my server -

python:

1. /usr/bin/python
2. /usr/bin/python3.7m
3. /usr/bin/python3.7
4. /usr/bin/python2.7
5. /usr/lib/python3.7
6. /usr/lib/python2.7
7. /etc/python
8. /etc/python3.7
9. /etc/python2.7
10. /usr/local/lib/python3.7
11. /usr/local/lib/python2.7
12. /usr/share/python
13. /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz